# access class variable in aspect class

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, aspectj, spring-aop

i am creating an aspect class with spring aspectj as follow

```
@Aspect
public class AspectDemo {
  @Pointcut("execution(* abc.execute(..))")
     public void executeMethods() { }

 @Around("executeMethods()")
    public Object profile(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
            System.out.println("Going to call the method.");
            Object output = pjp.proceed();
            System.out.println("Method execution completed.");
            return output;
    }

}
```

now i want to access the property name of class abc then how to acccess it in aspect class?
i want to display name property of abc class in profile method

my abc class is as follow

```
public class abc{
String name;

public void setName(String n){
name=n;
}
public String getName(){
 return name;
}

public void execute(){
System.out.println("i am executing");
}
}
```

How can i access the name in aspect class?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to get a reference to the target object and cast it to your class (after an `instanceof` check, perhaps):

```
Object target = pjp.getTarget();
if (target instanceof Abc) {
    String name = ((Abc) target).getName();
    // ...
}
```

The recommended approach (for performance and type safety) is to have the target mentioned in the pointcut:

```
@Around("executeMethods() && target(abc)")
public Object profile(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp, Abc abc) ....
```

But this will only match the executions on a target of type Abc.

Answer (score 1):

@Hemant

You can access the declaring type and its fields from the **ProceedingJointPoint** object as follow:

```
@Around("executeMethods()")
public Object profile(ProceedingJoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {

    Class myClass = jp.getStaticPart().getSignature().getDeclaringType();
    for (Field field : myClass.getDeclaredFields())
    {
        System.out.println(" field : "+field.getName()+" of type "+field.getType());
    }

    for(Method method : myClass.getDeclaredMethods())
    {
        System.out.println(" method : "+method.toString());
    }
    ...
}
```

Field & Method are part of the **java.lang.reflect** package

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Spring then you could use the AOPUtils helper class

```
 public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable
 {
      Class<?> targetClass = AopUtils.getTargetClass(invocation.getThis())
 }
```